# Override Document.execCommand() commands or methods

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

Modern browsers offer `contenteditable` which you can make an editable div. Each browsers has its own policy for newline for example Firefox uses `<br>` and Chrome uses `<div>`.

In addition `Document.execCommand()` provide some methods and commands for you that by using them you can change the default behaviors. for example by using bellow code you would be able to change the default paragraph separator to `<div>` and both Chrome and Firefox use `<div>` as a separator.

```
document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', true, 'div');
```

Although it is useful but in some cases I need to change mentioned code's behaviors. for example I need to add a class attribute for each new DIVs which are regarded as a new paragraph separator.

In some programming languages as like as `Java`, it is possible to override the default behaviors and also you can extend provided classes.

Now my question is, how can I override the `defaultParagraphSeparator` command of `document.execCommand()` in order to add a class attribute to each new DIV?

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: @zabusa I read following documentation but nothing has mentioned: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand